# Convert Symfony services.yaml and security.yaml into php format

Tags: php, symfony

I want convert all my configuration files from YAML to PHP format.

**QUESTION**

I have this services.yaml:

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    App\EventListener\ExceptionListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

My security.yaml

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto
    providers:
        users:
            entity:
                class: 'App\Entity\User'
                property: 'username'
```

What services.php and security.php equivalent should be? I tried services.php:

```
<?php

namespace Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\Configurator;

use App\EventListener\ExceptionListener;

return function(ContainerConfigurator $configurator) {
    $services = $configurator->services()
        ->defaults()
        ->autowire()      // Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        ->autoconfigure() // Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
    ;

    // makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    // this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    $services->load('App\\', '../src/*')
        ->exclude('../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Tests,Kernel.php}');

    // ?????
    // How to get $container here?
    // ?????
    $container->register(ExceptionListener::class)
        ->addTag('kernel.event_listener', ['event' => 'kernel.exception'])
    ;
};
```

and it doesn't work for me... I don't understand how to inject $container into this file

Comment: services.yaml and security.yaml are two completely different things.  The services file uses a service builder to build services.  The security file is just an array.  No way to combine the two.  Check the docs for examples.

Comment: @Cerad I just want convert all my configs into PHP format and official examples doesn't working for me

Comment: @yivi, sorry, my fault. I mean $container. I updated question. Previous code not enough because I need configure ExceptionListener

Comment: What do you mean by `$container`? Why are you trying to do that? The previous call to `$service->set()` does what you are trying to do...

Comment: @yivi I found this code in official documentation - https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html. I want specify my custom event listener. Yaml configuration work well for me, but I don't understand how to rewrite it into PHP format

Comment: Ok.  I see the confusion.  The example in the docs needs updating.  Use $services->tag() instead of $container->register.

Comment: @yivi without last line all working fine, but I need Event Listener...

Comment: But the `set()` call already does that for you. You register the service and set the tag... exactly what you want to do below. Your call to `$container->register()` is not needed.

Comment: @yivi - It's actually two distinct steps.  First you define the service with set then you tag it.  Or you could use $services->set('Class')->tag('some-tag');  Bottom line is that the docs need updating.

Comment: @Cerad That's **exactly** how [they had it in their question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63358723/4). That's my point precisely. For some reason in the latest edit they removed that line.

Comment: Your latest edit removed the **correct** way of doing it. Not sure what you are trying to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that the example of registering an event listener in the docs needs to be updated.  Something like:

```
# config\services.php
return function (ContainerConfigurator $configurator) {
    $services = $configurator->services()->defaults()
        ->autowire()
        ->autoconfigure();
    ...
    $services->set(ExceptionListener::class)
        ->tag('kernel.event_listener',['event' => KernelEvents::EXCEPTION]);
```

Off-topic but using an [event subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber) will eliminate the need to configure it.

As far as the security config file goes, it is just a big php array.  You start with the example in the docs and then it's just a question of figuring out the keys.  Here is an example that I think covers your question:

```
# config/packages/security.php

// Keeps IDE happy
/** @var ContainerBuilder $container */
$container = isset($container) ? $container : null;

$container->loadFromExtension('security', [

    'enable_authenticator_manager' => true, // 5.1 or later

    'encoders' => [
        User::class => [
            'algorithm' => 'auto',
            'cost' => 12,
        ]
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'user_provider' => [
            'entity' => [
                'class' => User::class,
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'firewalls' => [
        'dev' => [
            'pattern' => '^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/',
            'security' => false,
        ],
        'main' => [
            'lazy' => true,
            'provider' => 'user_provider',
            'guard' => [
                'authenticators' => [
                    UserLoginFormAuthenticator::class,
                ]
            ],
            'logout' => [
                'path'   => 'user_logout',
                'target' => 'home_index'
            ],
        ],
    ],
    // Don't want to go to far down this rabbit hole
    'access_control' => [
        ['path' => '^/admin',      'roles' => 'ROLE_ADMIN'],
        //['path' => '^/home',       'roles' => AccessListener::PUBLIC_ACCESS],
        ['path' => '^/user/login', 'roles' => AccessListener::PUBLIC_ACCESS],
    ],
]);
```